# What are the implications of forking the EntityManager a large amount of times in Mikro-ORM?

Tags: node.js, typescript, entitymanager, mikro-orm, identity-map

I'm building a back-end web server with Apollo Server Express and Mikro-ORM and following the docs, I found that the `fork()` method can be used to get a clean entity manager. I've used the function in the config object as part of the context.

```
const server = new ApolloServer({
    schema,
    context: async ({ req }): Promise<Context> => {
      const context: Context = {
        em: orm.em.fork(),
      }
      const token = req.headers.authorization || ''
      if (token) {
        try {
          const { uid, } = await auth.verifyIdToken(token)
          context.uid = uid
        } catch (err) {
          console.log(err)
        }
      }
      console.log(context);
      return context;
    },
    playground: true 
  });
```

While logging out the context as shown in the code, I found that all the forks are kept in memory (or it seems to be).

Output:

```
...
{ em: [EntityManager<743>], uid: 'XtaxEqnngWXklT4xOZUNmHbVO2f2' }
{ em: [EntityManager<744>], uid: 'XtaxEqnngWXklT4xOZUNmHbVO2f2' }
{ em: [EntityManager<745>], uid: 'XtaxEqnngWXklT4xOZUNmHbVO2f2' }
{ em: [EntityManager<746>], uid: 'XtaxEqnngWXklT4xOZUNmHbVO2f2' }
{ em: [EntityManager<747>], uid: 'XtaxEqnngWXklT4xOZUNmHbVO2f2' }
```

My question is if there will be negative consequences as a result of this at some point and if yes, how do I deal with this issue?

Comment: What makes you think they are still in the memory? You are just logging them, one by one.

Comment: @MartinAdámek The number that keeps increasing. Could you help me understand what that means?

Comment: Yes, the request id is different - you are creating new contexts, each one has its unique id.